# Filter multidimensional array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, filter

With an array like the following, how can I filter objects based on the texts.id? For example if I wanted to return this very same array without the texts object reffering to the id 123 how would I go about it? I have access to the id I want to filter out and also the name of the object where its located. I have been trying to figure this out but I am not sure this is doable with the filter method only. Thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

```
[
 0: Object {
  name: 'Name 1',
  texts[
   0: Obj{
    id: '123',
    body: 'test message'
   },
   1: Obj{
    id: '456',
    body: 'test message 2'
   }
  ]
 },

 1: Object {
  name: 'Name 2',
  texts[
   0: Obj{
    id: '789',
    body: 'test message3'
   },
   1: Obj{
    id: '101112',
    body: 'test message 4'
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Comment: post your expected result as well

Comment: You probably need to use two loops: one to iterate over the outer array, and a second to iterate over the inner `texts` property of each member of the outer array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear to me whether you want to remove the entire outer object where the `texts` array contains an object with a certain id (i.e: in your example, this would remove the whole object with name `'Name 1'`), or if you just want to remove the object in the `texts` array which has a certain id (i.e: leaving the outer object, just removing the object in texts with id `123`).

The former has been answered by @lissettdm above, but if it's the latter, you could do something like this:

```js
const filter = "123";
entry.forEach(item => item.texts = item.texts.filter(text => text.id !== filter));
```

Comment: Yes I want to remove the object inside texts (id and body) where the id equals the id I am searching for and return the rest of the array exactly as it was.

Comment: Hi there, what I've posted here should work then :) You can just replace `entry` by whatever the name of the variable containing your multi-dimensional array of objects is.

Comment: Yes that's what I did, thanks a lot mate, already accepted it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const entry = [{name: "Name 1",texts: [{id: "123",body: "test message"},{id: "456",body: "test message 2"}]},{name: "Name 2",texts: [{id: "789",body: "test message3"},{id: "101112",body: "test message 4"}]}];
    
const filter= "123";
const output = entry.filter(item => item.texts.find(text=> text.id===filter));
    
console.log(output);
```